# Create special WordPress slideshow with "jquery.cycle.all.js"

Tags: jquery, javascript, slideshow

i want to create my own slideshow without using any slider plugins
hear is my code

-- in the footer ---

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    timeout: 3000,
    pager: '#navSlider',
    slideExpr: '#mySlide'
});
</script>
```

in my front-page.php

```
<div class="slideContent">
    <div id="navSlider"></div>
    <div id="slideshow" class="pics" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="mySlide">
            <div id="textBack"></div>
            <div id="textSlide">the title 1</div>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/slideimage/myimage1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="mySlide">
            <div id="textBack"></div>
            <div id="textSlide">the title 2</div>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/slideimage/myimage2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-- in css file ----

```
#slideshow {
    width: 232px;
    height: 232px;
}
#navSlider {
    z-index: 50;
    position:absolute;
    width:19px;
    top:0;
    right:-5px;
}
#navSlider a {
    display:block;
    height:31px;
    margin: 0 0px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #cff;
    text-decoration: none
}
#navSlider a.activeSlide {
    background: #aaf;
    padding:9px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}
#navSlider a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#textBack {
    background-color:#000;
    /*color:#FFF;*/
    opacity: 0.4;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:232px;
    /*text-align:center;*/
}
#textSlide {
    color:#fff;
    height:26px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:10px;
    font-size:18px;
    /* margin:auto;*/
    /* width:232px;*/
    /* text-align:center;*/
}
.pics {
    height: 232px;
    width: 232px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.pics img {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.slideContent {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 244px;
    height: 234px;
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#069;
}
```

i create this and actually it works alone very nice but i don't know why it won't work in wordpress and is there any matter if there is another slider? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** use an external jQuery library, use the one that comes with WordPress.

Use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to enqueue your scripts, like:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Additionally be aware that WordPress sets the internal jQuery to `noConflict()` mode, more information about that [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Comment: so how to translate this to  wp_enqueue_script ?? what i wll do

Comment: Read the documentation I linked, it is pretty straight forward. @HadiOmary

Answer (score 1):

`id="mySlide"`is used twice in your markup. Just try removing `slideExpr: '#mySlide'` from your plugin options.

Try using `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`.

Comment: no this sounds good to me cuz i use it as selector for

Comment: Try ialocin's approach and keep in mind to enqueue jquery before enqueueing cycle

Comment: ok .... this is it ....thanx dud

Comment: i put this for test because i will replaced by "featured images"